# Pong game in canvas: unable to move players paddle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pong

I have created a pong clone for a projected in canvas and created paddles for the ball to bounce off. I've managed to link the arrow keys to event listeners but I'm having trouble moving the paddles along the x-axis. Any suggestion for how to achieve this?

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/blacksunmachine/pen/WNjOJLW

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d') 
let paddleX = (canvas.width - (drawPlayerPaddle.xCoordinate))

context.fillStyle = 'green'

function drawPlayerPaddle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height) {
    context.fillRect(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height)
}
drawPlayerPaddle(10, 10, 100, 10)

function drawComputerPaddle (xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height) {
    context.fillRect(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height)
}
drawComputerPaddle(280, 290, 100, 10)

let x = canvas.width/152;
let y = canvas.height-280;
let dx = 2;
let dy = 2;


function drawBall () {
    context.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20)
}
setInterval(drawPath, 10)

function reset() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 300)
}

function drawPath() {
    reset()
    drawBall()
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    drawPlayerPaddle(10, 10, 100, 10)
    drawComputerPaddle(280, 290, 100, 10)
    if(y + dy < 0 || y + dy > canvas.height) {
        dy = -dy
    }
    if(x + dx > canvas.width || x + dx < 0) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
}

let ArrowRightPressed = false
let ArrowLeftPressed = false

document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown) 
function handleKeyDown (event) {
    // right arrow
    if (event.key) {
        ArrowRightPressed = true
        console.log('Key down',event.key)  
        // left arrow
    } else if (event.key){
        ArrowLeftPressed = true
        console.log('Key down',event.key)
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp) 
function handleKeyUp (event) {
    // right arrow
    if (event.key) {
        ArrowRightPressed = false
        console.log('Key up', event.key)
        
        // left arrow
    } else if (event.key){
        ArrowLeftPressed = false
        console.log('Key up', event.key)
    }
}

function movePlayerPaddle() {
    if(ArrowRightPressed) {
        paddleX += 7
    }
}
```

I've set paddleX as the location of the player paddle:

```
let paddleX = (canvas.width - (drawPlayerPaddle.xCoordinate))
```

and to move the paddle Ive set up the function:

```
 function movePlayerPaddle() {
    if(ArrowRightPressed) {
        paddleX += 7
    }
}
```

but I'm not able to move the paddle.

I think the problem are that I'm not defining the the x-coordinates of the paddle well and because of this the buttons are not linked to the paddle so not moving it.

Suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: First error: In your event listener you are not checking which key is pressed/released. So always your code will set/unset `ArrowRightPressed` independent on which key was pressed

Comment: Also, where are you calling `movePlayerPaddle()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code.

1. You are not checking what key is being pressed.
2. You are not calling `movePlayerPaddle` anywhere.

I'll not write code for you, just give you the way to follow:

1. Inside your drawPath you are drawing the pads in a fixed coordinate. You must check if the move key is pressed and sum/subtract the coordinates to move it.
2. Change your event listener to check what key is being pressed to decide to set move left or right flag.
3. If it moves too fast, you can increment the coordinate in decimal steps, like 0.5 to move 50% slower.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @Elias I'll give that a go!